# How to Use INNER JOIN On BIGQUERY

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am new and learning SQL. I want to join data from two tables using a common key which is the department_id which exists in both tables. The challenge is that after I entered the data (i.e after the ON clause) in line with the study video with which I'm following, I keep getting error message as "unrecognized name". I don't know what it is I am not doing right.

Below is the statement for assistance please.

```
SELECT
  employees.name AS employee_name,
  employees.role AS employee_role,
  departments.name AS department_name 
FROM 
  my-learning-project-01092023.employee_data.employees 
 INNER JOIN 
  my-learning-project-01092023.employee_data.departments
ON
 employees.department_id=departments.department_id
```

I expect that after running this, I will get a result showing columns bearing employee_name,employee_role and department_name.

Comment: I find it easier to alias table names... makes it easier to read, write and troubleshoot.

Comment: _I expect that after running this, I will get a result showing columns bearing employee_name,employee_role and department_role._ But in your select statement, you are selecting `departments.name`. Why not `departments.role`? Perhaps that's your answer.

Comment: @Isolated , thanks for the suggestion. I must have made a typo error with the departments.role because what I actually intended was the departments.name as that is the column existing on my departments table. The point at which I encountered the challenge was where I intended joining the two tables data (ie. the employees table and the department table) using the field that exists on both (ie. the department_id) but from the point of entering the statement employees.department_id after the ON clause, it was flagged as 'unrecognized name'.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your SELECT clause is using aliases (employees, departments) but you haven’t aliased your tables.

Comment: thanks so much for your response. That is actually where the problem lies. I just did and everything worked.